# question on analytic extension

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic in the annulus $1<|z|<2$ and there exists a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ converging to $f$ uniformly on every compact subset of this annulus.

Show that $f$ has an analytic extension to all the disc $|z|<2$.

---

I tried to define $f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_r}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw, $for any $|z|\leq 1$, where $C_r=\{w| |w|=r\}$ for some $1<r<2$. Then, I need to show $f$ is analytic. But I got stuck in showing it is continuous on $C_1$, and I do not know how to use the polynomials $p_n$.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the maximum principle, the sequence $p_n$ converges locally uniformly on $|z| < 2$. The limit gives you your extension.